# PYTHON AUTH0 POST REQUEST: Invalid request payload JSON format

Tags: python, json, format, auth0

I'm trying to build a script that auto creates users in Auth0's user API
the emails i received off of another software, the print out of the email result looks like this:

```
{'update_id': '1570540963828', '59': '1570492800000', '16': 'xyz@xyz.com'}
{'update_id': '1570540932828', '59': '1570492800000', '16': 'abc@abc.com'}
```

However, when I tried to include this email result i got as an input into my http request, i get an error

```
{u'message': u'Invalid request payload JSON format', u'error': u'Bad Request', u'statusCode': 400}
```

this is what I have

```py
for r in response:
    #print r
    email = str(r['16'])
    data = '{"email":' + email +',connection":"Username-Password-Authentication","password":"blahblahblah"}'

    res = requests.post(url="https://xxxxx.auth0.com/api/v2/users", data=data, headers=headers)
    print res.json()
```

assuming i want all pw to be blahblahblah

any input appreciated!, i think it has somehting to do with the way I used those quotation marks.

edit: originally before i did this, i used a random email like sjd@shd.com inside the quotation marks and it worked, but now im trying to switch it to iterative email address list, its giving me that error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i solved it. turns out json=data worked instead of data=data

Answer (score 1):

Check below snippet complete code, I have updated line `data = {"email": email, "connection":"Username-Password-Authentication","password":"blahblahblah"}.`

```
import requests
response = [{'update_id': '1570540963828', '59': '1570492800000', '16': 'xyz@xyz.com'},{'update_id': '1570540932828', '59': '1570492800000', '16': 'abc@abc.com'}]

for r in response:
    headers = {}
    email = str(r['16'])
    data = {"email": email, "connection":"Username-Password-Authentication","password":"blahblahblah"} # updated line 

    res = requests.post(url="https://xxxxx.auth0.com/api/v2/users", data=data, headers=headers)
    print(res.json())
```

Comment: i solved it. turns out json=data worked instead of data=data